# "Practical writing" or is there a name for this type of essay?

Tags: word-choice, writing, letter-writing

I find that the English exam for [Chinese College Entrance Exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaokao) always likes to ask the examinee to write a specific type of essay, around 100-150 words, mostly in the form of letter, but sometime using the form of poster writing/summary writing. In Chinese we call that type of essay "practical writing"(应用文)

I guess it is called "practical writing" because it is written to solve a practical problem, e.g. writing an invitation letter to some friend, explaining an activity (the rules, the forms, etc) in the school and invite them to join in; writing a complaining letter to a store to address a specific problem; writing a letter to your English teacher to explain the problem you are facing and ask for help or introducing a less well known Chinese tradition. And I guess the purpose is to check whether students are able to use the language as a tool. To quote from some high school English teachers here, the purpose is to "To check students' ability to acquire information, process information, analyze and solve problems in English"

[The Chinese wiki](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87/4053193) has these words for 应用文, "There is no universal definition in the academic world and it probably won't have one but most people agree it has following features: practical, nonfiction, having targeted audiences ... "

But I never know there is a formal name for that type of writing in English, or it there any?

---- update ---

From the comments I got, especially from FumbleFingers and HippoSawrUs I think I can safely draw the conclusion that **expository writing** is the name I was looking for.

Comment: There will be *many* different "categorization schemas" for your context. Here's [What Are The Types Of Nonfiction?](https://jerichowriters.com/different-genres-of-non-fiction-complete-guide/), which says *they broadly fit into these categories: **expository nonfiction, narrative nonfiction, persuasive nonfiction**, and **descriptive nonfiction*** (e.g. - instruction manuals, history books, political tracts, travel guides, etc.). I doubt there's a single "standard" term within the educational sphere equivalent to that Chinese concept. But "expository nonfiction" might be "close enough".

Comment: Yes; every Anglophone school in the U.S., for example, has its own set of standards, measures, categories, rules, classes, and subjects. To begin with. There are no national standards or categories; Chinese educational culture is much more standardized than Anglophone. Some countries, like the UK, have national standards, but no one shares them.

Comment: Maybe it's a business letter?

Comment: I feel "business letter" is just one type of it, but as @FumbleFingers suggested "expository nonfiction",  I do feel it is close enough.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks  for the information but I feel it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: A *letter* (correspondence) and a *essay* (on a subject) is not the same thing in the U.S.

Comment: Yes I know. It is not always to write a letter, I happened to use some examples with letter.

Comment: Based on this site ( https://www.clarityenglish.com/program/practicalwriting/), "practical writing" covers both essay writing and correspondence writing, even though it is in their name, a proper noun in this case. (Late edit: *is* s/b *are*).

Comment: @HippoSawrUs man that can't be case because "practical writing" the words I came up with myself  lol.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗: I think Prof Lawler's comment has *everything* to do with your question. He's amplifying the point made in the first sentence of my initial comment - and very significantly, pointing out that "standardisation" is much more a feature of *your* cultural background than his or mine. Heck! He and I can't even agree on how to *spell* the word ***standardisation**!* (But he and his damned Yankee fellow countrymen are winning the fight; I've configured my browser for BrE spelling, but it still doesn't like my version in this comment! :)

Comment: I find the categories of nonfiction are quite similar between English and Chinese. Before asking the question I know we have **persuasive nonfiction, descriptive nonfiction and biography/memoir**. I didn't know the term **expository nonfiction and narrative nonfiction**. But once you pointed out, it is quite obvious we have those two, e.g. if narrative nonfiction is about a real-life story, of course we have that and if expository nonfiction is about sharing ideas and information we have that too. So it didn't came to my mine that it has anything to do with standardi[s|z]ation. lol

Comment: See "What is Expository Writing?" here. https://www.thoughtco.com/expository-writing-composition-1690624#:~:text=Expository%20writing%20is%20used%20to,understanding%20the%20world%20around%20us.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs thanks for the link. Now I think I can safely conclude that expository writing is what I was looking for.

Comment: I looked it up many times and only found a couple of sites that included letter writing in expository writing, but it's becoming more broadly defined as letter writing dies out and texting replaces emailing as often as possible, to paraphrase one site.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs letting writing maybe is just our thing.

Comment: [The Chinese wiki](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87/4053193) has these words for **应用文**,  "There is no universal definition in the academic world and it probably won't have one but most people agree it has following features: practical, nonfiction, having targeted audiences ... "